# TurtleBot -- Bad Gyro Calibration

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been running the SLAM map building tutorial with the turtlebot and I have been having a problem where the turtlebot image in Rviz does not rotate nearly as much as the actual real life turtlebot.  This causes the map that is being created to be completely wrong, as the turtlebot is not putting the data it finds in the right place on the map.  I have run the gyro and odometer calibration and have set the rosparams to the proper values.  I am also getting an error in Rviz under the robot model:

rear_wheel_link
No transform from [rear_wheel_link] to [/map]

and a warning under the path (path) and pose array (pose array) that says "no messages received"

as a further error, my turtlebot dashboard diagnostics is giving me an error:

Full name: /Sensors/Gyro Sensor
Component: Gyro Sensor
Hardware ID:

Level: Error
Message: Bad Gyro Calibration

Gyro Enabled: True
Raw Gyro Rate: 5
Calibration Offset: 5
Calibration Buffer: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

I feel that this is almost certainly related, but cannot figure out how to fix it.  I have run the calibration several times.  I have also tried cycling the power, to no avail.

Please help!  Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11061/turtlebot----bad-gyro-calibration/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2011-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To debug this you're going to need to disassemble your TurtleBot. You'll need a DMM as well.

Remove the platters from your TurtleBot so that you can get at the TurtleBot power board. Put your DMM in DC voltage mode and touch pins 8 and 14 with the DMM probes and to read the voltage. The voltage should be 5V.

- If the voltage is not 5V this is most likely a problem with your
  irobot create base.
- If it is 5V this is most likely a problem with your power board.

Top down view of the power board header pins:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rear_wheel_link warning is due to that link being unactuated and free floating it cannot be rendered due to lack of information.

The warning about the path is because a planning path has not been sent yet.  And when running SLAM gmapping doesn't publish the pose_array like amcl does.

The "Bad Gyro Calibration" is your problem.  Can you cut and paste the entire error from the dashboard for that error, and edit your question to include it?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2011-08-30**:
I tried power cycling the create, and that did not fix the problem.  I got the turtlebot kit from ClearPath Robotics and assembled it myself.  I cannot get to the power board without disassembling the entire thing.  It is a standard self-built turtlebot from the ClearPath kit though.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-08-30**:
Power cycle the create.. sometimes it powers on funny. Also if  you got your TurtleBot from WG can you tell me the serial number on your power board so I can look at the qualification test results.

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2011-08-30**:
I updated it!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I took it apart and ran those tests and it was generating 5V just fine in both the serial port directly and the power board.  Upon putting it all back together, it worked!  Perhaps the power board had just become a little unseated.  Either way, problem solved!

---

Originally posted by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) with karma: 122 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-07**:
the raw gyro value of a functioning TurtleBot while not moving should be between 425-575

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2011-09-07**:
Hi Aroarus, after you reassembled everything and the problem went away, what was your raw gyro value? Thanks, -Scott